# Which one is faster, selecting the element directly or selecting its parent first?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my DOM tree:

[image: this is my dom tree]

Given the options:

1. `d3.select("body").select("svg").selectAll(".circle_g")`
2. `d3.select("body").selectAll(".circle_g")`

Do you know which one is faster?

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb, the more selections you have the less performant the code is.

Therefore, if the target elements (class `circle_g`) are the **only** elements with that class, the best option is simply doing:

```
d3.selectAll(".circle_g")
```

The more selections you add, the slower the code. So, this will take longer to run:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll(".circle_g")
```

And, finally, this is the worst option:

```
d3.select("body").select("svg").selectAll(".circle_g")
```

This [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/d3-select-performance/1) clearly shows the differences in performance. The values I have in my machine are (around):

- `d3.selectAll(".circle_g")`: fastest option.
- `d3.select("body").selectAll(".circle_g")`: 11% slower.
- `d3.select("body").select("svg").selectAll(".circle_g")`: 20% slower.

It's worth mentioning that using a CSS space selector, like this...

```
d3.selectAll("body svg .circle_g")
```

... is more performant that the third option above, but still less performant than the first one (around 6% slower).

In short, don't select the parents, this is not only useless but also reduces performance. Go straight to the target: `d3.selectAll(whatever)`.

**EDIT**

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823174/which-one-is-faster-selecting-the-element-directly-or-selecting-its-parent-firs/54837998?noredirect=1#comment96490899_54837998) shed a light on your specific case, thanks for that.

Thus, in the very specific case that...

1. You have a huge amount of elements in the DOM
2. Your target elements are all in the **same** parent

... selecting the parent first will be slightly faster, because you don't have to search all the DOM for the target elements. So, in that specific case, this:

```
d3.select(parent).selectAll(target)
```

Is faster than this:

```
d3.select(target)
```

Have a look at this [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/d3-select-performance/4) to see some values in a not so crowded HTML. Give that specific case, the more elements you have in the page the biggest the difference.

Finally, it's worth mention that in production code this normally doesn't matter, because D3 programmers normally (or should I say hopefully?) use the parent's selection before a `selectAll`. Something like this:

```
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const circles = svg.selectAll(".circle_g")
//parent here----^
```

Comment: What if I have many elements whose class are circle_g, I think it need to search the whole DOM tree to do this operation, is it better if I select the father first?

Comment: @xhliang In some specific cases, yes, it is. Check the edit.